# Restriction on J2SE inbuilt method

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle, pmd

As per my company rule I can not use `stop()` of thread

For that I want something like when I use `stop()`, eclipse should shows error/warning
It is difficult to achieve by using checkstyle and PMD.

Comment: Thread's `stop()` method is deprecated and Eclipse already shows the warning for deprecated methods, what specific thing do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to consider using [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) instead of Checkstyle or PMD, because you need to know the runtime type of a variable in order to see whether it is an instance of `Thread` or not.

AFAIK, none of the tools has a built-in detector/check for your Thread.stop() rule, so you will have to [write a custom Findbugs detector](http://code.google.com/p/findbugs/wiki/DetectorPluginTutorial).

A simpler way of achieving this (but not suitable for an enterprise development environment) would be to simply check for occurrences of `Thread.currentThread().stop()` and the like using Checkstyle and a regular expression. Let me know in the comments if you would like an example for that.

Comment: For what it's worth, PMD has "type resolution" rules that can check the runtime type.  Not a built in rule there either.

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot over ride the stop() or other method inside java.* classes. You can use code scanners to search for stop() being called on instances of threads.

You could extend thread and then use that (in your class stop method can do nothing or throw and exception) but again you would have to mandate that every use that new class.

But why do they want you to do that? if your using multi threading use pools (and only create Runnable classes) or if you MUST use threads then have other methods to stop the processing of them (like a flag and checking the flag during processing, and having a setter to set the falg from other thread)

Comment: I am doing R&D since long with checkstyle and PMD but not able to achieve yet :(